# Reading Binary Data in () golang

Tags: go

I need to read a specific binary data format (https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/BT_file_format.htm). Go seems to be able to do so quite nicely:

```golang
// ...

    f, _ := os.Open(filename)
    var data struct {
        Indicator         [10]byte
        Columns           [4]byte
        Rows              [4]byte
        DataSize          [4]byte
        UTMFlag           [2]byte
        UTMZone           [2]byte
        LeftExtend        [4]byte
        RightExtend       [4]byte
        BottomExtend      [4]byte
        TopExtend         [4]byte
        FloatingPointFlag [2]byte
    }
    _ = binary.Read(f, binary.LittleEndian, &data)
// ...
```

That seems to work since `spew.dump(data.Indicator)` for example return the correct data. What I do not understand is how to cast fixed slices like `[2]byte` to an integer I can actually work with. Any suggestions?

Comment: Declare the field as `int16` or `uint16`.

Comment: Please consult [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#pkg-overview).

Comment: @CeriseLimón I was apparently confused about bits and bytes here. By you are write. Mind to write up an "answer" so I can accept it?

Comment: Also the format spec was incorrect for the data I used which lead to more confusion: http://vterrain.org/Implementation/Formats/BT.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the fields with fixed size numeric types:

```
var data struct {
    Indicator         [10]byte
    Columns           uint32
    Rows              uint32
    DataSize          uint32
    UTMFlag           uint16
    UTMZone           uint16
    LeftExtend        uint32
    RightExtend       uint32
    BottomExtend      uint32
    TopExtend         uint32
    FloatingPointFlag uint16
}
```

I used unsigned integers here, but it's also OK to use signed integers.  Use the type that matches the data.

https://play.golang.org/p/95yqMAYsWVR